# TRY/CATCH not working when table goes missing

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, rollback

I can't seem to get this to work... The result is SQL Management Studio seems to hang, gives me the message

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 76 Invalid object name

If I try to close the code window, I get a warning that the transaction isn't committed, and asks if I would like to commit it.  If I do, the truncate has happened, and the items are missing.

I'm trying to make sure the truncate does NOT happen or gets rolled back if the table in the "INSERT" statement is missing.

```
BEGIN TRY 
  BEGIN TRAN
    TRUNCATE TABLE X
    INSERT INTO TABLE X ([values...]) -- pseudo code; insert works fine if table is present
    SELECT * FROM  <potentially missing table>
  COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  if (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
    ROLLBACK

END CATCH
```

Comment: you don't even need transaction. each single statement is already in transaction and it will roll back if any error happens. in your case INSERT INTO is a single statement and you don't need transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the information provided it looks like it may be a problem with your syntax, but it is unclear without a CREATE TABLE statement and some working code. It could also be that you're not checking if the table exists before the SELECT. I just tested the below and it has the desired results.

```
BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRAN
    TRUNCATE TABLE [test_table]
    INSERT INTO [test_table] VALUES ('...')
    SELECT * FROM [test_table]
  COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
    PRINT N'rolling back transaction' --for confirmation of the catch
    ROLLBACK
END CATCH
```

Or to avoid the TRY/CATCH use IF EXISTS to check if the table exists before starting anything.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'test_table')
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRAN
    TRUNCATE TABLE [test_table]
    INSERT INTO [test_table] VALUES ('...')
    SELECT * FROM [test_table]
  COMMIT
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- do something else
    PRINT N'The table does not exist'
END
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Jon.  I guess I'm stumped about why I'd need to check if the table exists.  I was trying to use the Try/Catch to catch the error if it doesn't exist. Maybe that error doesn't get caught?

Comment: My mistake, I misunderstood. The TRY/CATCH will capture the error returned by all three of the statements if the table doesn't exist. It will be Error 4701 for the TRUNCATE and 208 for the INSERT and SELECT. You could very well avoid the entire TRY/CATCH with IF EXISTS logic if you don't need to capture the error for error handling. See the updated answer above.

Answer (score 1):

2020-10-11:

I tried `SET XACT_ABORT ON`, prior to engaging a transaction.
Interestingly, when encountering a missing table (e.g. at SELECT stmt), the script STILL halts **without** dropping into the `TRY/CATCH` block.

Moreover, and actually worse, all prior SQL output is no longer available.

Notwithstanding, the transaction was rolled back, as there is no open Transaction, thereafter.

PROOF:

1. executing "select @@TRANCOUNT"  returns 0
2. manually executing "ROLLBACK TRAN" states: "The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION."

I, therefore, decided to check for required tables, at script start/prior to engaging a Transaction, instead of using `XACT_ABORT`.